# Matrix Multiplication Using double pointers passing into functions in C

Tags: c, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I am wondering why I cannot get the value in the function, it always cause segmentation fault...
`

```
void multiply(int M, int N, int K, int **matrixA, int **matrixB, int **matrixC){
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < K; j++){
            int sum = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < N; k++){
                sum += (*(*(matrixA + j) + k)) * (*(*(matrixB + k) + j));
            }
            *(*(matrixC + i) + j) = sum;
        }
    }
    
}

int main(){
    int M, N, K;
    scanf("%d%d%d", &M, &N, &K);
    int matrixA[M][N];
    int matrixB[N][K];
    int matrixC[M][K];
    for(int i=0; i<M; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<N; j++){
            scanf("%d", matrixA[i]+j);
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<K; j++){
            scanf("%d", matrixB[i]+j);
        }
    }

    multiply(M, N, K, (int **)matrixA, (int **)matrixB, (int **)matrixC);
    for(int i=0; i<M; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<K; j++){
            printf("%d ", matrixC[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`

I want to print out the result "matrixC", but in the function, it would cause segmentation fault. I have tried several times, and it seems like it would miss the addresses of the pointer under the double pointers.

Comment: Why are you even using double pointers? If you want a function to work with arrays, then declare its arguments as (2D) arrays. Let the compiler do the "conversion to pointers" for you. The fact that you have to cast the arrays to `int**` should be a strong warning that 2D arrays **do not** automatically convert/decay to double pointers.

Comment: Well, technically, 2D arrays do become "double pointers" ... but not as you'd hope. A variable declared as (say) `int A[3][4]`, when passed as an argument, becomes a pointer to an array of 4 integers (not an `int**`).

Comment: Also, why do you insist on using pointer arithmetic for array elements, when the C language provides a perfectly serviceable `[]` operator: `scanf("%d", matrixA[i]+j);` is much easier to read as `scanf("%d", &matrixA[i][j]);`.

Answer (score 1):

Change the prototype of the function `multiply` to this:

```
void multiply(int M, int N, int K, int matrixA[M][N], int matrixB[N][K], int matrixC[M][K]);
```

make your life easier like this (body of function multiply):

```
for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) { //for each row of matrixA
    for (int j = 0; j < K; j++) { //for each column of matrixB
        matrixC[i][j] = 0; //set field to zero
        for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) { //for each col of A and each row of B
            //take the dot product of row i (matrixA) and col j (matrixB)
            matrixC[i][j] += matrixA[i][k] * matrixB[k][j];
        }
    }
}
```

You have an error in this line

```
sum += (*(*(matrixA + j) + k)) * (*(*(matrixB + k) + j));
```

which has been corrected to

```
matrixA[i][k] //index 'i' not 'j'
```

The var `sum` is not needed, therefore opted out.

---

**Based on your comment below**

Consider the following code:

```
int arr[2][2];
int n=0;

for (int i=0; i < 2; ++i) {
    for (int j=0; j < 2; ++j) {
        arr[i][j] = ++n;
        printf("%p (%d)  ", &arr[i][j], arr[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Possible output:

```
0x7fff7c729470 (1)  0x7fff7c729474 (2)  
0x7fff7c729478 (3)  0x7fff7c72947c (4)
```

As you can see, nicely packed into consecutive integers (basically one array of ints - but that is not guaranteed).

Now have a look at this:

```
int **parr = (int**) arr;

for (int i=0; i < 2; ++i) {
    for (int j=0; j < 2; ++j) {
        printf("%p ", *(parr + i) + j);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Possible output:

```
0x200000001 0x200000005 
0x400000003 0x400000007
```

Now, that looks (dangerously) ugly.

---

As always: pointer != array. Pointer to pointer means, an address of another address, whereas an array is a consecutive block of a type (you could for example take the address of the first element, which is done if the array decays to a pointer).

You have to give the compiler enough information, e.g.

```
int (*parr)[2] = arr;
```

See also: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array#Multidimensional_arrays

Comment: Finding the actual math error was what I failed to do (and why I didn't post an answer). Well spotted!

Comment: @AdrianMole Yes, i too saw it not until i wrote the clean code. Too much clutter are misleading your eyes, easy to miss the important things.

Comment: Thank you so much! But I am quite curious about why it would have an error if I  pass double pointer into the function. Thanks!